# Aggregated Class is displaying the default constructor

Tags: c++, class, aggregate

I'm writing a Ticket Simulator program for my c++ class. I have a class named `PoliceOfficer` within a class named `Parking Ticket`. When I display the `officer.print()` function in the source, it displays the correct information that the user provided. But when, i user the `officer.print()` function within the ParkingTicket class it displays the nothing, meaning the default constructor. Hopefully this makes sense. Here's my code:

```
class PoliceOfficer
{
private:
ParkedCar car;
ParkingMeter time;
std::string name;
int badgeNumber;

public: 
PoliceOfficer()
{
    name = "";
    badgeNumber = 0;
}

PoliceOfficer(std::string i,int j)
{
    name = i;
    badgeNumber = j;
}
void set(std::string i, int j)
{
    name = i;
    badgeNumber = j;
} 
std::string get_name() const
{
    return name;
}
int get_badgeNum() const
{
    return badgeNumber;
} 

void print() const
{
    std::cout << "Police Officer Information: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name: " << get_name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Badge Number: " << get_badgeNum() << std::endl;
}
};
```

Parking Ticket class:

```
class ParkingTicket
{
private:
    ParkedCar car;
    PoliceOfficer officer;
    ParkingMeter time;
    double fine;
    int hours;

public:
    double baseFine = 25.0, hourlyFine = 10.0;
    ParkingTicket(int i = 0, int j = 0)
    {
        fine = i;
        hours = j;
    }
    void set_fine() 
    {
        hours = (time.get_MinutesPurch() - car.get_minutesParked()) / 60;
        fine += baseFine;
        fine += hours *hourlyFine;

    }
    void ticket_print() const 
    {
         officer.print();
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Ticket Information: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Minutes in Violation: " << (car.get_minutesParked() -        time.get_MinutesPurch()) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Fine: $" << fine << std::endl;

    }
```

};

source :

```
int main()
{
    string oname;
    int bnum;
    PoliceOfficer officer;
    ParkingTicket ticket;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, oname);
    cout << "Enter your badge number: ";
    cin >> bnum;
    officer.set(oname, bnum);
    officer.print();
    ticket.ticket_print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set information for `PoliceOfficer` inside of `ParkingTicket`?

Comment: I don't? do i have to? I thought it would just take the information from it being set within the police officer class

Comment: @Thao `ParkingTicket` seems to need an initialized reference of a `PoliceOfficer` class instance.

Comment: Those are two different `PoliceOfficer`s, like `int bnum` in `main` and `int hours` in `ParkingTicket` are two different `int`s. You will either need to set `ParkingTicket` member right, or make it reference as @πάνταῥεῖ suggested.

Comment: @Thao you cannot define class with spaces (class parking Ticket). It must be compile time error

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo That happened when I was writing this post. It doesn't have the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PoliceOfficer` object in your main() is not the same as the `PoliceOfficer` inside your `ParkingTicket` class.

```
ticket.officer.set(oname, bnum);
ticket.officer.print();
ticket.ticket_print();
```

This would work if `officer` was not private, so you may have to make it public
or create a function that returns a reference or a pointer to your private officer member:

```
ticket.officer().set(oname, bnum);
ticket.officer().print();
ticket.ticket_print();

ticket.officer()->set(oname, bnum);
ticket.officer()->print();
ticket.ticket_print();
```

Here's another alternative:

```
ticket.set_officer_details(oname, bnum);
ticket.print_officer_details();
ticket.ticket_print();
```